# Drupal css and theme is not showing

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I am having a problem with the Drupal I have successfully set up the site from the live server to the local host. I have uploaded the data base to the local host and connected to it. Now When I try to run the site through the local host. 
Only the text of the site is loaded while the theme,css and the images are not loaded.
I am new in the drupal.
I am not sure about the problem.
Please help me to locate the problem. 
Thank you very much.

```
Errors in the console are as follows,
•   The resource from “http://localhost/site/docroot/” was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).[Learn More]  docroot
•   ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined[Learn More]  docroot:927:1
•   Unknown property ‘-moz-box-shadow’.  Declaration dropped.  default+de.css:209:17
•   Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘progid’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  default+de.css:231:10
•   Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  default+de.css:250:10
•   Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  default+de.css:262:10
•   Unknown property ‘-moz-box-shadow’.  Declaration dropped.  default+de.css:554:17
•   Unknown property ‘zoom’.  Declaration dropped.  default+de.css:788:6
```

Comment: Any errors you can post, or existing code you believe might have contributed to the problem would greatly increase your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: And check the browser console for errors - if you see 404 errors, or 'not found' errors, it means that the database is using hard coded links to assets.

Comment: Please see the post again I uploaded the errors in the console.

Comment: Excellent. Now try editing the post again with examples of steps you've tried to resolve these issues - you have errors you can search on Google now.

Comment: I am able to find the problem. Actually when i first time start the project it download some files in the directory C:\wamp\www\test\site\docroot\sites\default\files
but Instead of downloading the complete folder it just download the empty folder with no images in it.
Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: Maybe permission problems? Better ssh to original server, zip whole site and download the archive. It's safer than downloading file by file.